# How to use choice option in python for my py file?

Tags: bash, unix, python, bash-scripting, python3

I am running [Prawler](https://github.com/priyamharsh14/Prawler) to get proxies.

I installed this with the instructions given on GitHub. It works fine too, but I would like to add a choice option in it.

To get a proxies, I use this following code:

```
import Prawler;
Prawler.get_proxy_txt("proxy_list.txt", 50, "http", "elite")'
```

I would like this to ask me which type of proxy I need. For example, the expected output:

```
Choose Proxy type,
option 1 - http
option 2 - socks4
option 3 - socks5
choose one option from above >
```

If I type 1 and press enter, it replaces the proxy type to http

If I type 2 and press enter, it replaces the proxy type to socks4

If I type 3 and press enter, it replaces the proxy type to socks5

In my main code:

for http option,

```
import Prawler;
Prawler.get_proxy_txt("proxy_list.txt", 50, "http", "elite")'
```

for socks4 option,

```
import Prawler;
Prawler.get_proxy_txt("proxy_list.txt", 50, "socks4", "elite")'
```

for socks5 option,

```
import Prawler;
Prawler.get_proxy_txt("proxy_list.txt", 50, "socks5", "elite")'
```

I don't know how to make it ask for my choice option here in Python. I am new to python. Kindly help me to proceed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it with Prowler, but this should work.

It stores the input as a `str` named `option`.

It checks to see if the input `option` is in the `dict` named `proxy_types`. It will loop until you enter either `1`, `2`, or `3`.

When a valid input is found, it uses `option` as a *key* to retrieve the correct *value* from `proxy_types` - either `http`, `socks4`, or `socks5`. It then breaks out of the loop, and calls `get_proxy_txt` with the chosen `proxy_type`.

```
import Prawler

proxy_types = {"1": "http", "2": "socks4", "3": "socks5"}

while True:
    option = input("""Choose Proxy type,
    option 1 - http
    option 2 - socks4
    option 3 - socks5
    choose one option from above > """)
    if option not in proxy_types:
        print("Invalid option selected. Choose again.")
        continue

    proxy_type = proxy_types[option]
    break

Prawler.get_proxy_txt("proxy_list.txt", 50, proxy_type, "elite")
```